# basic search of filestube using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am trying to use selenium IDE to search filestube.to and I error at the xpath.
I used firebug to aquire the xpath and paste it directly into selenium and get the following error;

```
[error] Element /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input not found
```

code:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

complete output:

```
[info] Executing: |open | / | http://www.filestube.to/ |
[info] onXhrStateChange(): xhr.readyState = 1 method = HEAD time = 1408504217417
[info] onXhrStateChange(): xhr.readyState = 2 method = HEAD time = 1408504217693
[info] onXhrStateChange(): xhr.readyState = 4 method = HEAD time = 1408504217694
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input | |
[error] Element /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input not found
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably loaded through javascript and doesn't appear immediately.

Try doing a waitForElementPresent or waitForVisible on a previous step before clickAndWait.

Answer (score 0):

bad user error.
instead of manually entering the xpath, I used the ide